# java ListResourceBundle checkstyle

Tags: java, localization, checkstyle

I am trying to use **ListResourceBundle** for localizing my web app. It works well but checkstyle shows warning

```
public class Locale_en_US extends ListResourceBundle {
     @Override
     protected final Object[][] getContents() {
         return new Object[][]{
                 {"Login.Enter-with", "Enter with"},
                 {"Login.Hello", "Hello"},
                 {"Login.Test-Description", "You will have 40 minutes after "
                        + "starting test, to finish it"}
       };
   }
}
```

And after use it:

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Locale",request.getLocale());
String testDescr=resourceBundle.getString("Login.Test-Description")
```

`"Name 'Locale_en_US'` must match pattern `'^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.".`

Is where any way to fix this except of changing checkstyle ruleset?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I edited your post.  I marked down a keyword using two asterisks.  And I marked down your error using >

I think you need to show us more of you code, style sheet etc.

Comment: Can you add some code? I don't know what I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i found solution:
I created property file "Locale_en.properties" with content:

```
Login.Enter-with=Enter with
Login.Hello=Hello
Login.Test-Description=You will have 40 minutes after starting test to finish it
```

And then changed to

ResourceBundle.getBundle(**"/Locale"**,request.getLocale())

Now it works same way, but it doesn't require use of class.

P.S. sorry for my broken english.

Answer (score 0):

I added the [SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filters.html#SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter) to the checkstyle configuration:

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter">
        <property name="commentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE IGNORE THIS LINE"/>
        <property name="checkFormat" value=".*"/>
        <property name="influenceFormat" value="0"/>
    </module>
    <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
```

Then it is easy to ignore the warnings:

```
public class DemoClass_DT { // CHECKSTYLE IGNORE THIS LINE
  private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger =
          org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoClass_DT.class);

  private LocalDate D; // CHECKSTYLE IGNORE THIS LINE
  private int [] array;
}
```

This works with checkstyle 8.41.1.